# How to change django template variable value in javascript code?

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-templates

I've got a video on my html page. When a user click a button, the video begins. When the video ends, I need to change the users parameter 'views_num'. Here is my Javascript code:

```
document.getElementById('get-views').onclick = function() {
  var videoE1 = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
  videoE1.play();
  videoE1.addEventListener('ended', function () {
    {{ user.views_num| add:5}}
  }, false);
};
```

So when I enter the html page and click the button, the video does not play automatically and I need to start it with the control button. Also after the video ends the 'views_num' does not change. How can I change the variable value?
P.S. The views_num is an IntegerField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change Python/Django variables in JavaScript. You should create separate url and view in Django and call this view asynchronously with ajax after video has ended. You should pass the id of the user in the view and than raise its views_num and return for example a JsonResponse. See the code bellow. Of course you should pass user to the context of the template in order to use `{{ user.id }}` in `$.get`.

```
urls.py
path('user/count-views/<int:user_id>', views.count_views, name='count_views')

views.py
def count_views(request, user_id=None):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=user_id)
    user.views_num += 5
    user.save()
    return JsonResponse(data=user.views_num, safe=False)


# Call count_view via constructed url after video has ended
videoE1.addEventListener('ended', function () {
    $.get("user/count-views/" + {{ user.id }});
  }, false);
```